# pie3D: x values must be positive numbers

Tags: r, statistics

I load the supportdata variable as follows.

```
supportdata=aggregate(scoredata$Support, list(Topic = scoredata$Topic), sum)

slices <- supportdata[2]

lbls <- supportdata[1]

typeof(slices)
```

## 3D Exploded Pie Chart Below

```
pie3D(slices,labels=lbls,explode=0.1,main="Year wise scores for topic 1")
```

and I get the below error:

> Error in pie3D(slices, labels = lbls, explode = 0.1, main = "Year wise
>   scores for topic 1") :pie3D: x values must be positive numbers

supportdata variable contains the following information and is generated using aggregate function which sums up the scores in the second column.

```
# supportdata
#
#    Topic  x
#
#  1     c   14
#  2     c#  80
#  3     c++ 15
#  4     css  4
#  5     html 3
#  6    .net  3
#  7     php  0
#  8     sql  0
```

How do I get rid of this error? I tried searching but couldn't find a solution to this problem..I tried casting into as.numeric, as.integer but it says the list cannot be coerced into double or integer type. :(

Comment: presumably `pie3D` is telling you it can't handle your zero-width slices.  What if you change those values to something very small but positive?

Comment: I can't reproduce even with zero values.  Can you edit in the results of `dput(supportdata)`, please?

Comment: try `slices <- supportdata[[1]]`.

Comment: @BenBolker > dput(supportdata)
structure(list(Topic = structure(1:8, .Label = c("c", "c#", "c++", 
"css", "html", ".net", "php", "sql"), class = "factor"), x = c(14, 
80, 15, 4, 3, 3, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Topic", "x"), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")
>

Comment: I want to do slicing based on the second column and then label them using the values in the first column - names of languages in the pie chart

Comment: Zero is not a problem because I am trying to do the same thing with other columns where none of the values is zero and I face the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is indexing with `[` rather than `[[`, which returns a *list* of numbers rather than a *numeric vector*.

```
library("plotrix")
pie3D(supportdata[[2]],labels=supportdata[[1]],
      explode=0.1,main="Year wise scores for topic 1")
```

works fine, as does

```
with(supportdata,pie3D(x,labels=Topic,
      explode=0.1,main="Year wise scores for topic 1"))
```

Comment: Hi Ben, Thanks ...It works..Yes...That was the root cause...I tried using the below and it worked fine too. I did a transpose of the input list.

Answer (score 1):

The below solution works too apart from one provided by Ben.

```
slices <- t(supportdata[2])
lbls <- t(supportdata[1])
pie3D(slices,labels=lbls,explode=0.1,main="Pie Diagram for Support")
```